# google maps api marker composed of image and line

Tags: google-maps, line, google-maps-markers

Is it possible with "Google Maps Api" to obtain a marker composed of a line and ends with a picture?

I tried to use a marker consists of a single image (eg, line and circle) and if there are 2 adjacent markers will be covered from the first second.

For example I have marker like this:

```
--0
```

and the second it's close the result is:

```
--0-0
```

I must rotate so the result is:

```
--0
\
 0
```

how I can make this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to  [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) the attribute anchorPoint.

Using the Marker position you can detect a possible overlap between images, and change that value and image to do what you need.

Comment: can you show me a example of overlap detection? i don't find it

Comment: I was thinking on a simple function, that given two positions and zoom, detects overlapping. 
Suppose we have our Picture rectangle with the left bottom vertex where the position(parameter), then, if the other position is on that rectangle the overlap is detected, and change the image an image offset, also  you can use the zoom as size factor to adjust the rectangle.